# Why does $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{-4x^2-4x}}$ simplify into $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2-x}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> Why does $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{-4x^2-4x}}$ simplify into $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2-x}}$?

What's going on here? How is it being simplified?

Comment: factor out $4$ and take it outside sqrt lol

Answer (score 5):

$$\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{-4x^2-4x}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{4(-x^2-x)}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{4}\sqrt{(-x^2-x)}}\\
=\dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{(-x^2-x)}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(-x^2-x)}}$$

Comment: you missed $-$ thing inside sqrt

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Thanks!

Comment: @SantoshLinkha See my edit.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Dylan Sure!${}{}$